# Replace hex character used as field delimiter to pipe

Tags: linux, hex, csv

I have a .dat file sitting on Centos where the data is delimited by non-printable characters.

The field delimiters are Hex (`1D`) and the end of record delimiter is Hex (`0D0A`). If I `cat` the file, it looks something like this:

```
field1^]field2^]field3^M$
```

Question: is there a way for me to replace Hex `1D` with a 'pipe' delimiter (or any other suitable delimiter) so that I can pull the data into excel for some analysis? My plan is to then split the fields into columns in excel using pipe as a delimiter.

One problem I see here with replacing with pipe is that if one of the datasets within the fields also accidentally has a pipe then the data could be split incorrectly i.e. based on the above example, I could potentially end up with more than 3 columns.

Alternately, is there any other way I should be approaching this problem? End goal is to get the data formatted properly to visualize either in Excel or Tableau.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways in which you can translate this.  The simplest is probably to use `tr`.

> **`tr`** `[OPTION]... SET1 [SET2]`
>
> Translate,  squeeze, and/or delete characters from standard input,
>   writing to standard output.

```
tr '\035' '|' < data.file
```

(`tr` only supports octal escapes `\ooo`, and 0o035 is 0x1d.)

(The record delimiter is already a (dos-style) CRLF newline, which most programs should understand.  So that should be all you need to do.)

Comment: You are a legend. Worked like a charm and also learned something new which is always good.